# Complex type pode ter propriedade Entity Type?

Tags: entity-framework, ddd

Tenho uma classe Endereco que é ***Complex Type***. Ela pode ter uma propriedade Estado que é uma ***Entity Type***?

Código das classes:

```
public class Endereco
{
   ...
   public string Logradouro { get; set; }
   public Estado Estado { get; set; }
}

public class Estado
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Nome { get; set; }
}
```

Mapeamento das classes:

```
public class EnderecoConfiguracao: ComplexTypeConfiguration<Endereco>
{
   public EnderecoConfiguracao()
   {
       ...
       //fields
       Property(e => e.Logradouro).HasColumnName("Logradouro").HasMaxLength(200);
    }
}

public class EstadoConfiguracao: EntityTypeConfiguration<Estado>
{
    public EstadoConfiguracao()
    {            
        //Key
        HasKey(e => e.Id);

        //fields
        Property(e => e.Nome).HasColumnName("Nome").HasMaxLength(50).IsRequired();

        //table
        ToTable("estado");
    }
}
```

No meu modelo, o Cliente tem um Endereco, mas ao tentar mapear a propriedade Estado desse endereço ocorreram os seguintes erros:

1º Erro: Se eu mapear Estado da mensagem *“Hba.HbaTools.Infraestrutura.EntityFramework.Estado: Name: Each type name in a schema must be unique. Type name 'Estado' is already defined.”*

2º Erro: Se eu comentar o mapeamento de Estado da mensagem *“Unknown column 'Extent1.Endereco_Estado_Id' in 'field list'”*

---

Como estou iniciando ainda com Entity Framework, pensei em retirar Estado da classe Endereco, mas se essa for a melhor solução **eu estaria alterando meu modelo de domínio devido a restrições do framework? Seria correto fazer isso?**

---

Comment: como você está começando com Entity Framework, talvez seja interessante você utilizar a abordagem `Code First from database` e estudar o código gerado... mas de cara posso dizer que estou sentido a falta do `virtual` em `public virtual Estado Estado { get; set; }`, afinal se trata de uma propriedade de navegação.

Comment: dá uma olhada neste modelo obtido atraves do [`Code First from database`](http://csharppad.com/gist/996ca9a51be0e8177878)

Comment: @TobyMosque eu não coloquei `virtual` porque eu li que *Complex Type* não pode ter propriedade de navegação. Procede? No modelo de exemplo que você me enviou no link, a classe Endereco não deviria estar com o atributo [ComplexType]?

Comment: este modelo foi gerado pelo VS apartir do Banco.

Comment: talvez este link lhe ajude a entender alguns aspectos [Entity Framework 6 (7) vs NHibernate 4: DDD perspective](http://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/2014/11/29/entity-framework-6-7-vs-nhibernate-4-ddd-perspective/), segundo o autor um dos problemas do EF, é que o mesmo lhe força a pensar sobre a pespectiva do banco de dados sem um isolamento do modelo de dominio. Então no seu caso o melhor seria remover o `ComplexType`, unificando ele a Entidade `Cliente` no Modelo ou criando uma tabela `Endereco` no Banco de Dados.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Renan, agora entendi o seu problema. Infelizmente não é possivel referenciar uma `Entidades` em `Tipos Complexos`.

Então para manter esta estrutura, você terá de transformar `Endereco` em um `Entidade`, descartar `Endereco` e mover as suas propriedades para `Cliente` ou remover a propriedade `Estado` de `Endereco`.